# How can i create a shortcode in wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress, shortcode

I have the code below and i want it to display content on implementation using

```
[insert_dos]*Content for dos here*[/insert_dos]

[insert_donts]*Content for dos here*[/insert_donts]
```

**Dos**

*Content for dos here*

**Don'ts**

*Content for don'ts here*

***The code am trying to use***

```
// Shortcode for dos
       function insert_dos_func( $atts,$content ) {
    extract( shortcode_atts( array(
        'content' => 'Hello World',
        ), $atts ) );

      return '<h2>DOs</h2>';
      return '<div>' . $content . '</div>';
    }
    add_shortcode( 'insert_dos', 'insert_dos_func' );



// Shortcode for don'ts
        function insert_donts_func( $atts ) {
          extract( shortcode_atts( array(
            'content' => 'Hello World',
            ), $atts ) );

          return "<h2>DON'Ts</h2>";
          return "<div>" . $content . "</div>";
        }
        add_shortcode( 'insert_donts', 'insert_donts_func' );
```

Comment: 2 returns won't work ... once you hit the first one that exits the function, next one never gets executed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first issue you're going to face is the use of multiple return statements inside a single function. Anything after the first return won't be executed.

The second issue is the way you're passing in content. There's an element in your attributes array named `content`. If you run extract on that array it's going to override the `$content` argument of your shortcode callback.

```
function insert_dos_func( $atts, $content ) {

    /**
     * This is going to get attributes and set defaults.
     *
     * Example of a shortcode attribute:
     * [insert_dos my_attribute="testing"]
     *
     * In the code below, if my_attribute isn't set on the shortcode
     * it's going to default to Hello World. Extract will make it 
     * available as $my_attribute instead of $atts['my_attribute'].
     *
     * It's here purely as an example based on the code you originally
     * posted. $my_attribute isn't actually used in the output.
     */
    extract( shortcode_atts( array(
        'my_attribute' => 'Hello World',
    ), $atts ) );

    // All content is going to be appended to a string.
    $output = '';

    $output .= '<h2>DOs</h2>';
    $output .= '<div>' . $content . '</div>';

    // Once we've built our output string, we're going to return it.
    return $output;
}
add_shortcode( 'insert_dos', 'insert_dos_func' );
```

Comment: just what i needed. Thxs alot